# SQL server--> Inserting multiple rows into a table with identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I wanna insert a multiple rows into a table with identity column

I have a table called `'STU'` with the following columns:

- SNO (Primary Key, and Identity [i.e. autoincrementing])
- NAME (not null)
- CLASS (not null)
- SECTION (not null)

  `CREATE TABLE STU (SNO INT IDENTITY (1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_SNO PRIMARY KEY (SNO), 
   NAME VARCHAR(25), CLASS VARCHAR(20), SECTION CHAR );`

The values are got inserted while executing insert query for each row individually

```
INSERT INTO STU VALUES('A','1','A');
INSERT INTO STU VALUES('B','2','B');
INSERT INTO STU VALUES('C','3','C');
INSERT INTO STU VALUES('D','4','D');
INSERT INTO STU VALUES('E','5','E');
```

but while trying to insert multiple values using single insert query in every possible shots, it took throws an error

```
 INSERT INTO STU (SNO,NAME,CLASS,SECTION) 
 VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
 ,('A','B','C','D','E','F')
 ,('1','2','3','4','5','6')
 ,('A','B','C','D','E','F');
```

also

```
INSERT INTO STU (NAME,CLASS,SECTION) VALUES 
('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
('1','2','3','4','5','6'),
('A','B','C','D','E','F');
```

also

```
INSERT INTO STU (NAME,CLASS,SECTION) VALUES 
('A','1','A'), 
('B','2','A'),('C','3','A'), 
('D','4','D'),
('E','5','E'),
('F','6','F');
```

also

```
  INSERT INTO STU (SNO,NAME,CLASS,SECTION) VALUES 
 (NULL,'A','1','A'), 
 (NULL,'B','2','A'),
 (NULL,'C','3','A'), 
 (NULL,'D','4','D'),
 (NULL,'E','5','E'),
 (NULL,'F','6','F');
```

Comment: What is your SQL server version? 2005 or 2008?

Comment: SQL server 2008 and 2012

Comment: Why did you tag as `sql-server-2005`? inserting multiple values using `Values(),(),..` method does not work on 2005 (as per my answer).

Comment: @Spidy note: this would have been a lot more straightforward if you posted the errors in your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2005, use `UNION ALL`

```
INSERT STU (NAME,CLASS,SECTION) 
  SELECT 'A' AS NAME,'1' AS CLASS, 'A' AS SECTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', '2', 'B'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', '3', 'C'
```

Versions later than 2005, you could use

```
INSERT STU (NAME,CLASS,SECTION) 
VALUES ('A','1','A'), 
       ('B','2','B'), ...
```

Comment: I altered the table and gave IDENTITY (1,1) for SNO.! I failed to mentioned it in the question now i corrected it in the question.!

Comment: In your last insert query, you are inserting `null` to `SNO` which is not possible. If it is an auto incremented identity column, you do not have to insert anything into it.

Comment: I have asked few helps from other forum there they gave me this suggestion of inserting null to auto-incremental column..!

Answer (score 1):

All your Insert statements are bad:

1. Make sure you are supplying the same number of columns as in the INSERT statement
2. Make sure you are not supplying SNO (it's automatic)

Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO STU (NAME,CLASS,SECTION) VALUES 
('A','B','C'),
('1','2','3'),
('A','B','C');
```

Comment: Look at my fourth insert query in this question..! I've tried this already this query it throws:
 
    Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SNO', table 
'master.dbo.STU'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It is correct. You just didn't have the identity set up even though you said he did in the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as:

```
INSERT INTO STU VALUES
('A','1','A'),
('B','2','B'),
('C','3','C'),
('D','4','D'),
('E','5','E');
```

Comment: Look at my first insert query in this question..!
I've tried this already this query it throws

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @Spidy please check the demo herE: http://rextester.com/GVTI86579 what I've suggested is correct.. also the first insert query in question didn't worked because in second row you are tring to add 6 values for only 4 columns that too one of which is Identity column.

Comment: It is correct. he just didn't have the identity set up even though he said he did in the question

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate the SQL you had in your first example.

You can't insert into the identity column (unless you turn identity insert on of course).

```
INSERT INTO STU (NAME,CLASS,SECTION) 
VALUES 
  ('A','1','A'), 
  ('B','2','A'),
  ('C','3','A'), 
  ('D','4','D'),
  ('E','5','E'),
  ('F','6','F');
```

If you do want to turn identity insert on then you'd need to do the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT STU ON

INSERT INTO STU (SNO, NAME,CLASS,SECTION) 
VALUES 
  (1, 'A','1','A'), 
  (2, 'B','2','A'),
  (3, 'C','3','A'), 
  (4, 'D','4','D'),
  (5, 'E','5','E'),
  (6, 'F','6','F');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT STU OFF
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41d99/1)

Comment: Look at my last insert query in this question..! I've tried your first option already this query it throws: 
`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SNO', table 'master.dbo.STU'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.`
**I don't wanna insert SNO column values manually, i don't wanna disturb auto-increament. Auto incremental should do as wat i ask it to do**

Comment: If SNO is an identity column then the first query should work correctly. You are not including SNO in the list of columns, nor in the list of values.

Comment: See SQL Fiddle I've added.

Comment: @samjudson You had some statements the wrong way around - I hope you don't mind me correcting them.